# Java - Can't read from InputStream, until OutputStream is closed

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to read and write to the bash/cmd. I'm starting the process with the process builder. 
Reading and writing to the command line works perfeclty the first time. But when I've written something to the command line, I can't read from the InputStream until I've closed my buffered writer. When I close the buffered writer, I can read from the command line again.
Is there a conflict between the outputStream and inputStream when I'm doing it like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "jdb" + path);
                processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process process = processBuilder.start();
                BufferedReader bufferedReaderInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader bufferedReaderError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
                String currentLine = "";
                while ((currentLine = bufferedReaderInput.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    bufferedWriter.write("hello");
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    //If I close the bufferedWriter here, I can read again from the bufferedReader.
                }
                while ((currentLine = bufferedReaderError.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    consoleWindow.appendText(currentLine);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

Comment: Knowing the exact command you're running in bash could be helpful here.

Comment: what is the intended purpose of this section of code in your program? is it to run a command entered by the user? please explain.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. I'm trying to start the java console debugger with jdb and the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
bufferedWriter.write("hello");
```

to:

```
bufferedWriter.write("hello\n");
```

Without '\n' it's like typing "hello" in jdb but not pressing enter.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed my problem :)